# List of Multiple Checkboxes and Textfields

Tags: java, list, checkbox, random

I want to create a list in java, to show a various number of panels, which include a checkbox, a textfield and a button. Then I want to check if for example checkbox_1 is checked. If so, then call the number from textfield_1. I don't know how i can check explicit the textfield_1 or checkbox_1. With a for-loop i make every checkbox with same variable name. Sure you have a solution for me :)

I hope my drawing helps you to understand my question.

[image: list with checkboxes, textfields and buttons]

thanks :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code please

Comment: Maybe use a JTable. It allows you to display row/columns of data in a single component. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information.